# Ruby on Rails: Transfer specific data from one heroku application to another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, heroku

I have two heroku applications, staging and production. As the names would suggest, we use the staging app for testing/new code. Once we deem that it's relatively bug free we move it to production.

The one thing this doesn't translate to is data. We might add a bunch of data to staging to see how it looks, then have to do it again in production to for the general user to see it.

For example, we have a news reader which pulls in stories from many different RSS feeds. Say we add 20 Feeds to staging and decide that they're all good for production. Is there any way to wright a method that connects to the production database from staging and adds each feed? I'm aware that there are ways to do this by overwriting the whole database but that doesn't work here since user specific data in production would be deleted.

Comment: Create a custom rake task to do this as needed: http://railsguides.net/how-to-generate-rake-task/

Comment: @WesFoster Thanks but how would I then tell the rake task to read from staging and write to production?

Comment: You wouldn't set it up to read from staging, you would simply set it up to repeat the tasks you did in staging to load in the new data. Without knowing more about your specific situation, it's hard to say exactly how to do that. But for quickly adding new data in a production server, rake tasks are amazing

Comment: @WesFoster The staging data was added by hand, not loaded in. That's why I'd like to have a way to avoid doing it twice